# QR code for links within questions and answers, regarding testing on mobile devices

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Very often there are questions where the source code or an example has to be tested/viewed on a mobile device. I find it very circuitous (hope this word fits) to:

- open the Stackoverflow page on the mobile, search for the question again, open the link **or**
- type the link into the browser directly

The first one is just a long way to take and the second can get kind of annoying, regarding URLs like `mywebsite.com/mobile-test/Capital-letTer-HashValue429asf/` or just `jsfiddle.net/3QOod83` (where this is still quite OK).

So, the question is: *How do I get the link onto the mobile with little effort?* I was thinking: Wouldn't it be nice to have QR codes attached to the links, so that the user can simply take a picture of the code directly from the screen?

---

I've created a mockup in Photoshop, how it could look. A click on the icon would show the code, a click anywhere else would hide it again:

**Normal view**
[image]

**Mouse over**
[image]

**Click**
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, isn't the issue getting the link on the mobile device? How is the QR going to help (unless your printing the question...) ? It seems like all you need is a way of sending the link to your mobile device...

Comment: Yeah, the issue is to get the link onto the mobile device. I thought QR would be one solution. Any other thing, with the same result would be awesome, too. Taking a picture of the QR was one of the first things, that came to my mind. Here is a little discussion on what dimensions a QR on screen should have: [What is the optimal QR code size on screen?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21065/what-is-the-optimal-qr-code-size-on-screen).

Comment: OK, I see what your saying now. Nice idea.